# Preventing a Defined Name Range from changing

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently setting up a workbook that utilizes command buttons to import information, chart it, and open a new tab with a specified name.  In the initial "Data" tab, I have a named range using the following code:

```
=OFFSET(**Data**!$B$2,0,0,COUNTA(**Data**!$B:$B)-1)
```

When the new tab is created, it renames the original "Data" sheet and creates a new one with the original name.  My question is how do I prevent the bolded name from changing in the defined name?  Is this possible and if not--is there a VBA code that would copy this and force me to give it a name?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You will have to use VBA and its a bit tricky. Can't you simply make a copy of the **Data** sheet and then rename it? That will not change the reference in the named range

Comment: What outcome are you trying to prevent here? Copying the sheet will also create a copy of the defined name, but that copy will point to the new sheet, not to `Data`

Comment: I suppose I could--I didn't consider this just because I have it set up so it's being renamed as the chart is being made.  To make sure I'm understanding you correctly:  Copying "Data" would allow it to retain it's name and preserve the reference even with there technically being 2 "Data" sheets?  I will give this a try, Thank you both!

Comment: @F.Angel07 Yes because previously when you rename the sheet the data reference gets updated automatically where as if you change the name in the copy it wont

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, either you can make a copy of the **Data** sheet and then rename it. This will work because when you rename the sheet the data reference gets updated automatically where as if you change the name in the copy it wont formulas referencing the copied sheet will get updated.

Else you can add this code to the end of your macro which will recreate the named range

```
ThisWorkbook.Names("abc").Delete
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="abc", RefersTo:="=OFFSET(Data!$B$2,0,0,COUNTA(Data!$B:$B)-1)"
```